# List of people with fields for demographic information

Tags: 7, nodes

I have two D7 projects where I need to create lists of people. The people will not have control of their profile and their profiles are information based; titles, academic/sports teams they participate, experience, education etc. When articles are written and the article is about or includes their name, the article will link to their profile. For example, one is a list of high school staff and students the other a list of elected representatives. When the lists are created I plan on using views to view the list alphabetically, by title, education, grade level, activities etc.

**sample fields:**
first name
middle name
last name
maiden name
title
date of birth
URL with description that will link to news articles about them
College
College major

How do I create a content type that will allow me to do this? What modules should I use? The content profile I have created requires a Title and Body. The Body I could use for misc. info. but I cant seem to be able to create a list that will do the above without the Title. And I am hoping to learn how to do this properly.

Fairly new to Drupal. Thank you.

Comment: you should be able to create the content with core modules. Create a content type and add Fields appropriate to the information you want to include. Title is always required at some level, but you can use a module like [Automatic Nodetitles](https://www.drupal.org/project/auto_nodetitle) to hide the title if you desire

Comment: Can the OP follow-up and share how this was handled? I have a similar project.

Comment: absolutely - if a solution was figured out by the author, with or without assistance from the community, they are encouraged to add their own answer and accept it once available